# How can I launch the ball based on the position of the touch on the screen?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I am trying to make a game where you are rquired to set the angle and speed of a ball that has to bounce on specific platforms in order to get to the destination.

Now, how do I find the direction from where the finger touches, to the ball, in order to make it move "away from the finger".

I have tried to use the subtraction of vectors in order to get the direction but It does not work since the vectors are relative to the world origin...it always gives me a wrong direction...

How do I solve this problem, I need a direction vector relative to touch and player(the ball), not to world, so I can launch the ball.

You will see that in the next picture I am simulating a touch with the mouse arrow(let say the mouse arrow is the finger of the player.I want to launch the ball based on the distance and position of the finger relative to the ball. It works well in the code BUT ONLY if the ball is placed on the origin of the scene, so i think it's a mathematical problem with vectors that I don't know how to resolve...

[image: Game]

Below is the code that I have by now. It is attached to the ball's gameobject:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour {

    [SerializeField]
    Camera playerCamera;
    Rigidbody rb;
    Vector3 touchPostion;

    private void Awake()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }
    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            LounchPlayer();
        }
    }

    void LounchPlayer()
    {
        Vector2 mousePos = Input.mousePosition;
        touchPostion = (transform.position - playerCamera.ScreenToWorldPoint(
                                            new Vector3(mousePos.x, 
                                                       mousePos.y, 
                                                       playerCamera.transform.position.z))).normalized;
        rb.AddForce(touchPostion.normalized, ForceMode.Impulse);
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the ball have it's own `Vector` also? That way you can tell which direction the ball is moving relative to the `World Vector`? Then you can calculate the direction between the player `Vector` and the `World Vector`, then make the ball move in that calculated direction?

Comment: What do you mean? I only need a vector direction so I can use the rb.AddForce() function...

Comment: If you get the `Vector` related to the mouse arrow and the world, then wouldn't that also be the `Vector` that the player is supposed to move in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When finding your touch position, the z component of `ScreenToWorldPoint`'s parameter should be an appropriate distance along the camera's forward vector, definitely not the camera's world z position. `playerCamera.nearClipPlane` is appropriate here, but really any small constant (such as `0`) would suffice.

Also, there is no need to normalize the launch direction twice.

```
Vector2 mousePos = Input.mousePosition;
touchPostion = (transform.position - playerCamera.ScreenToWorldPoint(
        new Vector3(
            mousePos.x, 
            mousePos.y, 
            playerCamera.nearClipPlane))
        ).normalized;  // This isn't a position vector; it's a direction vector. 
                       // The var name "touchPosition" is misleading and should be changed.

float launchMagnitude = 1f; // change this to adjust the power of the launch

rb.AddForce(touchPostion * launchMagnitude , ForceMode.Impulse);
```